# How to configure rmi service exporter endpoint address?

Tags: java, spring, service, rmi

i have exported some rmi services .

```
 <bean id="entityRmiServiceExporter" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="entityService"/>
    <property name="service" ref="entityServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="IEntityService"/>
    <property name="registryPort" value="1099"/>
</bean>
```

When run on my machine endpoint is **127.0.0.1:1099** 
but on VM it is **10.0.2.15:1099** ,ip address.

```
RmiServiceExporter:276 - Binding service 'entityService' to RMI registry: RegistryImpl[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[127.0.0.1:1099](local),objID:[0:0:0, 0]]]]
```

where can i configure it manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use placeholders in your Spring configuration and move the specific values to a properties file. To do that, you first need a bean that will resolve properties from file:

```
<!-- Read file that contains properties -->
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:app.properties" />
</bean>
```

Next you can modify your `entityRmiServiceExporter` bean to use the values from that file:

```
<bean id="entityRmiServiceExporter" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="entityService"/>
    <property name="service" ref="entityServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="IEntityService"/>
    <property name="registryPort" value="1099"/>

    <property name="registryHost" value="${rmi.endpoint}"/>
</bean>
```

And you need an app.properties file with a line like this:

```
rmi.endpoint=10.0.2.15
```

### Alternative approach

According to the [RmiServiceExporter Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiServiceExporter.html), there might be an alternative approach. This Javadoc says:

> Note: RMI makes a best-effort attempt to obtain the fully qualified host name. If one cannot be determined, it will fall back and use the IP address. Depending on your network configuration, in some cases it will resolve the IP to the loopback address.

You can tell RMI what the machines hostname is by passing `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=server.mycompany.com` to your JVM when its launched.

This means you don't have to configure your Spring bean - instead, you configure your JVM to expose the RMI interfaces on a different interface. If your machine is directly exposed to the internet (i.e., no firewall or something in between), I would not do that. If the machine is inside a company network, it might be acceptable or even preferable to solve it this way.

Comment: thanks, is default registryHost 127.0.0.1 ? why it works differently on VM ?

Comment: Because how a VM interacts with your network stack is different. It's still a local address, hence the `10.*.*.*`.

Comment: To clarify, java.rmi.server.hostname doesn't affect the bind-address: it determines the IP address or host name embedded in the stub. It doesn't have anything to do with local interfaces: for example, it can be the other, public side of an NAT device which is set up to do port forwarding.